# Alexa skill acount linking

Tags: python, flask, jwt, alexa-skills-kit

I have a REST API defined using Python Flask, and I would like to make http requests to that API through the use of an Alexa Skill.

```
@app.route('/auth', methods=["POST"])
def auth_user():
    data = request.get_json()
    users = db.users
    logged_user = users.find_one({'username' : data["username"]})
    if logged_user is not None and bcrypt.check_password_hash(logged_user['password'], data['password']):
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=data["username"])
        return jsonify({'logged_user':logged_user,'access_token':access_token})
    else:
        return "Invalid password or username"
```

As you can see above I check if the credentials are correct and then I send the acess_token in the response. The remaning endpoints then require the jwt the execute the requests.

How can I do this with an Alexa skill? How can I first autenticate the user in the API?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do account linking between Amazon's registered user and your system. It's quite a big subject. You can read more here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/understand-account-linking.html

Comment: Seconded. Once account linking is setup the authentication token will be included in the context of the skill execution, allowing you to access it and pass it for any subsequent REST calls from within the skill. It's a nice system.